# On rings and semirings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $R$ be a semi-ring (resp. a ring).
Let $\hat{R}$ be the structure obtained by "allowing infinite sums" in $R$ so 
$$\hat{R} := \lbrace\sum_{i \in I} a_i| a_i \in R\rbrace,$$
where $I$ is countable set.
 So my question is:

1. Is $\hat{R}$ a semiring (resp. ring)?
2. If we assume $R \neq 0$ does it follow that $\hat{R} \neq 0$?

Edit: After being closed, I rewrite the question as follows: 
 Given a semiring $R$. Assume we would like to make sense of infinite sums in $R$, so is there a way to define a sort of "completion" to $R$ which allow to make sense of infinite sums?
Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't call "allowing infinite sums" to what you define. It's not even a set if you don't bound $I$.

Comment: I correct the bound on $I$. Thanks


Comment: I am not sure what your notation means.  Is $\hat{R}$ just the set of set-theoretic functions from $I$ to $R$?

Comment: @Carnahan: Yes we can say so.

Comment: can we say in this case that $\hat{R}$ is a completion of $R$?

Comment: In that case, addition and multiplication can be defined pointwise.  Perhaps you are looking for a different notion of "infinite sum"...

Comment: And what about the non-triviality issue ($R \neq 0$)?

Comment: @Ali Bleybel, what relations do you put on the elements of $\hat{R}$? 
When in your definition, are two such sums equal? 

Comment: @Liran Two such sums are equal when the inidividual terms in the sums are equal. Does this make sense?

Comment: Does anything prevent you from choosing a nonzero element $r$ in $R$, and setting $a_i = r$ for all $i \in I$?

Comment: No, nothing prevents. Why?

Comment: I'm still confused at what the notation should mean. If this is the set of infinite formal sums (i.e. the ring $R^I$) then this is not quite what one would expect from the description. Shouldn't there be some kind of mechanism that identifies finite sums with their value in $R$?

Comment: @Ali Bleybel, in this case the ring you are looking at is simply the direct product of $|I|$ copies of $R$.

Comment: I am not sure if the thing is well-defined at all. For instance, let $a,b\in R$. Do you then identify $a+b$ (addition in $R$) with the formal infinite sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty }a_i$, where $a_1=a$, $a_2=b$ and $a_i=0$ for $i>2$?

If you want this and other "obvious" relations to hold, then I think you *always* have $\hat{R}=0$.

Comment: If you want $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1$ to be $1 + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1$ (which is a rather reasonable thing for sums to satisfy - how else would you compute sums?), but also want $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1$ to be $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1$ (by a substitution of $i\mapsto i-1$, since it is a bijection), you get $0=1$. Welcome to Hilbert's hotel.

Comment: I don't see here any definition of multiplication that was approved by the proposer of the question.  S. Carnahan mentioned a definition, but he seems quite doubtful about it, and it seems to have gotten no response from Ali Bleybel.  So I would answer Question 1 in the negative.  You can't have a ring or a semi-ring without a definition of multiplication.

Comment: Okay, we've had a lot of interaction with the questioner, but there doesn't seem to be any clarification forthcoming.  I'm closing until the question is edited to a meaningful state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was pointed out in the comments that if we mean by  "$\sum_i a_i$" just the $I$-tuple $(a_i: i \in I)$, then the family of such tuples can of course be made into a semi ring (e.g., by pointwise addition and multiplication, or Cauchy multiplication if you use the index set $\mathbb N$).  But in this case, neither the notation/name "sum" makes sense to me, nor does question 2 make sense: $R^I$
is never empty for nonempty $R$.

So I will reinterpret the question: Which semirings can be extended to complete semirings?  By "complete semiring" I mean a semiring  $(S,+,\cdot,0,1)$ (with commutative addition) in which all  sums  $\sum_{i\in I} a_i$ (for all index sets $I$, or at least for all countable $I$) are defined and satisfy reasonable laws, in particular:

- infinite associativity and commutativity
- left distributivity: $c\cdot \sum_i a_i = \sum_i c\cdot a_i$, and similarly right distributivity; in particular, the sum of 0s is 0.
- finite sums agree with addition.

If you also impose the following (natural, I think) condition, called "d-completeness" or "discrete completeness":

- Whenever $\sum_{i=0}^n  a_i = a_0$ for all $n\ge 0$, then also 
  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_i = a_0$

then it is easy to see that the following are equivalent.

1. The semiring $S$ is a subsemiring of a complete semiring.
2. $S$ can be partially ordered by $a \le  b$ iff $\exists x\ a+x=b$.
3. For all $a,b,c$ in $S$, $a+b+c=a$ implies $a+b=a$.  (Of course, as Darij Grinberg has pointed out, this is never true in rings.)

The point is that $a+(b+c)+(b+c)+\cdots = a+b + (c+b)+(c+b)+\cdots$.  A few details can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208134).
Georg Karner's paper "On limits in complete semirings" (Semigroup Forum 45 (1992), no. 2, 148–165, MR1171841 (93h:16078)) has more information, and uses topological concepts rather than order-theoretic ones.

Comment: Thank you for your very nice answer! Maybe it will fit my purposes.

Comment: Does anyone have the paper "On limits in complete semirings" in pdf? I don't have access to Springer.